# On-Premise SharePoint 2019 End of life

Tags: sharepoint, upgrade, sharepoint-2019

I am using SharePoint 2019 (On-Premise) version for Document Management System, but according to Window Website [SharePoint 2019 end of life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sharepoint-server-2019) , the SharePoint 2019 will be Mainstream End Date on Jan 9, 2024.

I would like to plan for upgrade the SharePoint 2019, due to my company require using the On-Premise version, may I know advice for it?

Answer (score 0):

This means that SharePoint 2019 will no longer receive security updates, patches, and technical support from Microsoft on the Jul 14, 2026.

I suggest you use SharePoint Server Subscription Edition or SharePoint Online.